# ParseClientConfiguration - unresolved ios sdk v1.12.0

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-server

In the Parse.framework header folder, I can see ParseClientConfiguration.h but yet in the code I still cannot call this constructor, any ideas?

I've got the following in the AppDelegate:

```
let parseConfiguration = ParseClientConfiguration(block: { (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
            ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "APP_ID"
            ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "CLIENT_KEY"
            ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "http://www.testparseabc.com"
        })

Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(parseConfiguration)
```

ParseClientConfiguration keeps saying unresolved.

Comment: Are you trying to initialize parse in your app delegate?

Comment: yes but point it to a different server

Answer (score 0):

did you put the code in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**? Did you import **Parse** in AppDelegate? Your code work for me and the app will build successfully...

Comment: did all that. Parse was already there before trying to make this call. It worked when I used the existing parse template but not with existing project that I have. Very weird.

Comment: I would try to Clean the build and delete Derived Data, after that close the xcode and try to Build the app again... there is nothing wrong with the code